# Pay before posting (frontend insert post)

Tags: forms, wp-insert-post, paypal

I have a form on the frontend which I want users to fill out, when they have I want to save the data and redirect them to pay before submitting the post. How do I save the data before they pay?

I have a cookie working that lets me know when they have successfully paid. If they haven't paid then the form action looks like this:

```
$form_action = get_bloginfo('template_url').'/Checkout/paypal_ec_redirect.php';
```

Can I pass these post variables to the above page somehow?

```
$new_post = array(
    'post_title'    => $_POST['title'],
    'post_content'  => $_POST['description'],
    'post_status'   => 'draft',           
    'post_type' => 'listing'                 
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use sessions to store the data. There is a plugin also for that which I have used in the past and it works quite good.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-session-manager/